# Is it legal to use `record` as a variable name even though it's a keyword?

Tags: java, jls, java-17, java-record

This came as a surprise: I am able to declare a variable with the name `record` even though it now has become a keyword. Have a look at this:

```
public class Main {
    
    static class Foo {
        void bar() { System.out.println("Foo.bar"); }
    }
    
    record R (int a) {}
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo record = new Foo();
        record.bar();
        
        R r = new R(5);
        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

When compiled and run with Java 17 this gives:

```
Foo.bar
R[a=5]
```

I had expected this to result in an error as is the case when trying to declare a variable named `class`. As I know the Java guys, they are extremely careful not to break existing code, and so I think this might be a deliberate choice.

(You can't even declare a variable named `const` because that one [`const` *is* a keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9) in Java.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, this is legal because `record` is not a **reserved** keyword; it is only
a **contextual** keyword.

The Java Language Specification has distinguished between contextual keywords (originally "restricted keywords" and later "restricted identifiers") and reserved keywords since Java 9, due to the introduction of several new keywords in that version. The rationale is given in JLS 9 ([§3.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9)):

> A further ten character sequences are restricted keywords: `open`, `module`, `requires`, `transitive`, `exports`, `opens`, `to`, `uses`, `provides`, and `with`. These character sequences are tokenized as keywords solely where they appear as terminals in the `ModuleDeclaration` and `ModuleDirective` productions (§7.7). They are tokenized as identifiers everywhere else, for compatibility with programs written prior to Java SE 9.

Essentially, `Foo record = new Foo();` has to be legal in Java 17 because it was legal in earlier versions when `record` wasn't any kind of keyword, and backwards compatibility is a very high priority for new versions of the Java language.

Answer (score 8):

OK, while looking up `const` in the JLS again, I saw that `record` is a ***contextual** keyword* whereas `const` is just a *keyword*. Contextual keywords are parsed according to context, and when the parser determines that it's not looking at a a record declaration, it will not complain.

Comment: This really makes sense.  One can easily imagine that the number of times the word "record" appears as a field or local variable name in the codebase is huge.

Comment: This problem of adding keywords to evolve Java while not breaking existing apps has prompted a proposal to allow hyphenated keywords. See [*JEP draft: Keyword Management for the Java Language*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8223002).

Comment: @BasilBourque That document cites hyphenated keywords as just one of several possible strategies, including "contextual keywords", "reserved identifiers", etc.  In reality, we will likely use all of these strategies to balance evolution, expressiveness, and compatibility.

Comment: Close, but `record` (like `var`) is also restricted as a type name.  So it is allowable to have a variable named `record`, but not a class named `record`.  (So you can't say `record record(record record) {}`.)  This shouldn't be a big imposition because of the well-established naming conventions.